Concatenate sales month names in DAX
Using the AdventureWorks dataset, I need to create the following report in Power BI: First column has CustomerKey, second column Total Sales of this customer, and third column the distinct concatenation of the names of the months when that customer made a purchase.
For the last column, I have the following DAX measure:
Months when sales happened = CONCATENATEX(VALUES(Sales[OrderDate].[Month]), Calendar[MonthName])

With VALUES() I get the distinct list of months where the customer made the purchase, and Calendar[MonthName] returns the month name. Last, CONCATENATEX concatenates the names of the months.
The error I get in the measure is:

A single value for column 'MonthName' in table 'Calendar' cannot be
determined. This can happen when a measure formula refers to a column
that contains many values without specifying an aggregation such as
min, max, count, or sum to get a single result.

How to make this work?

Your measure is giving you an error stating it can't determine a single value for Calendar[MonthName] for a given value in the related auto date/time table of your Sales[OrderDate] column.
Edit: Here is a new measure that gives you the months where sales happened for a given evaluation context.
Months when sales happened =
VAR _sales_months =
    SUMMARIZE (
        'Date',
        'Date'[Month],
        'Date'[Month Number],
        "Sales", COUNTROWS ( Sales ) 
    )
VAR _filtered =
    FILTER ( _sales_months, [Sales] > 0 )
RETURN
    CONCATENATEX ( _filtered, 'Date'[Month], ", ", 'Date'[Month Number], ASC )

This assumes that order date is the active relationship between Date and Sales tables.
See example on dax.do:
https://dax.do/Hn8XjazrX91Mna/

wouldn't VALUES ( Sales[OrderDate] ) return a distinct list of dates instead of months?

You undeniably have a point! Late night DAX-ing proves to be a bad idea. I’ll look some more into it in a couple of hours.

I have updated with a new solution now, it also sorts months chronologically - not sure if that is just a nice to have. If so, remove the last couple of arguments in CONCATENATEX.

Try:
Months when sales happened = 
  var tMonths =
    SUMMARIZE(
      Calendar,
      Calendar[MonthName],
      "rows", COUNTROWS(Sales)
    )
  RETURN CONCATENATEX(FILTER(tMonths, [rows] > 0, [MonthName], ", ")


SUMMARIZE does not remove blanks, so this will give all months for all customers.

Good catch, thanks. Updated answer above, which is duplicative of yours, so all good.
